# No Route Matches with Japanese in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, constraints

I want a URL like `/posts/category1/category2/` so I wrote the following in `routes.rb`:

```ruby
class CategoryConstraints
  def self.matches?(request)
    xparams = request.params[:k].split("/")
    xparams & Category.pluck(:name) == xparams
  end
end

RailsApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "/posts(/:k)" => "posts#index", constraints: CategoryConstraints
end
```

It works perfect with romaji category names, but when the category name is in Japanese, such as when I visit `/posts/新規開発/`, a the following error is raised:

```
No route matches [GET] "/posts/%E6%96%B0%E8%A6%8F%E9%96%8B%E7%99%BA/
```

I think it is because Japanese characters were converted to Unicode, so `route` did not work. If I change to `constraints: {k: /.*/}`, everything works, but I cannot process the logic in `constraints` as with the first way (the `routes` return false without visit the `CategoryConstraints` class). Please help me do that with additional logic as with the first way.

Comment: Acctualy, this is a filter with params is the name of `category`, so I must check all params are exist in `Category` or not.

Comment: Um...is it faster? And when I use a link like `/posts/category1/something_does_not_exist` can I raise the `404` error? Could you please explain more?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `category.name` isn't stored in unicode format, so it doesn't match what's in `xparams`.  You'll want to be sure both values are unicode, so you can match them properly.

I think this similar question may resolve your issue:

[How to convert text to unicode in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182380/how-to-convert-text-to-unicode-in-rails)

Comment: I have checked. Both of them are `Unicode`. The problem is: The request fail outside of `CategoryConstraints`(If I have `initialize` function inside `CategoryConstrains`, the `request` == `nil`), that I cannot do any check or convert. It just happens when I use this way, if I changes the constraints to `{k: /.*/}` everything work perfectly.